# How to get extra data with django's orm?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, backend

How can I get extra data when returning query results, I want to know if the currently logged in user has liked the post or not, I think the solution would be something like this:

```
        return Post.objects.all().annotate(like_count=Count('likers'), liked=(len(Like.objects.filter(user=info.context.user, post=Post)) > 0)).order_by('-like_count')
```

but I couldn't get it to work

The post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="posts")
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   commentCount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The like model:

```
class Like(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
      related_name="like") 
   post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
      related_name="likers")
```

Comment: Could you add the models as well to help us understand it better?

Comment: @Saiprasad Balasubramanian yes